# How can I tell if a printer will print to file?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, io

I have a .net 2.0 application (c#) with one component running as a service and a UI for configuring the service.

The UI provides a way for the user to select a printer which will be used by the service.

I want the UI to filter out any printers which are configured to print to file becasue these pritners will cause problems for the service (a 'save as' dialog will open but the dialog is invisible becasue it belongs to the service).

The problem is that I can't find any method to detect a printer which is set to print to file.

System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings has a property called PrintToFile, but this is always set to false!

Comment: And a genuine printer may display "please load more paper" - basically, any printer *may* want to display UI.

Comment: Yes, my cannon printer love popping up some progressbar and dialogs

Comment: Added to which, I believe most printers are installed on a per-user basis - whereas services tend to run under machine accounts - so the service may not have access to the printer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but the messages you mention would not be displayed when a print job is created - they are displayed during the actual printing. The messages are therfore displayed to the logged in user (if there is one), and not within the context of the process which spooled the job.

Answer (score 1):

PrinterSettings.PrintToFile can only be set by System.Windows.Forms.Printing.PrintDialog class. The Print to file option only appears on the System.Windows.Forms.Printing.PrintDialog when the System.Windows.Forms.Printing.PrintDialog.AllowPrintToFile property is set to true.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, but it does not help me. I need to know if a printer has already been configured, through printer properties, to print to file. And I need to kow this before sending a new print job. Also, there are applications 'out there' which add a virtual printer for printing to PDF - I'd like to know how I can detect them too! From the responses so far, it looks like it can't be done.

Comment: First take second part of your question: Please use 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.installedprinters' property. It gets a collection of installed printers. You can use the collection of installed printer names to provide the user a choice of printers to print to. For first part of your question, please check PrinterSettings class if it works out for you.